# Pandas Group then rolling and sum get wrong results

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group column A then sum last 3 rows of column B.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df['B'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I tried.

```
df['sum_B_previous_3'] = df.groupby('A').B.shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum()
df

    A   B   sum_B_previous_3
0   1   1   0.0
1   1   2   1.0
2   1   3   3.0
3   1   4   6.0
4   2   1   5.0
5   2   2   4.0
6   2   3   3.0
7   2   4   6.0
```

But I want.

```
    A   B   sum_B_previous_3
0   1   1   0.0
1   1   2   1.0
2   1   3   3.0
3   1   4   6.0
4   2   1   0.0
5   2   2   1.0
6   2   3   3.0
7   2   4   6.0
```

Why row 4 and 5 get wrong results? How to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call lambda function per groups with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum()
df['sum_B_previous_3'] = df.groupby('A').B.apply(f)
print (df)

   A  B  sum_B_previous_3
0  1  1               0.0
1  1  2               1.0
2  1  3               3.0
3  1  4               6.0
4  2  1               0.0
5  2  2               1.0
6  2  3               3.0
7  2  4               6.0
```

Another solution is call `groupby` again:

```
df['sum_B_previous_3'] = (df.groupby('A').B
                            .shift(1)
                            .groupby(df['A'])
                            .rolling(3, min_periods=0)
                            .sum()
                            .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)

   A  B  sum_B_previous_3
0  1  1               0.0
1  1  2               1.0
2  1  3               2.0
3  1  4               3.0
4  2  1               0.0
5  2  2               1.0
6  2  3               2.0
7  2  4               3.0
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! But I have a question. Why my answer get the result from the last group?

Comment: @yolox - because `df.groupby('A').B.shift(1)` return new `Series` and `.rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum()` working with it, same like `df['sum_B_previous_3'] = df.groupby('A').B.shift(1)`

`df['sum_B_previous_3'] = df['sum_B_previous_3'].rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the only group operation you are applying is `.shift`. The result of `df.groupby('A').B.shift(1)` is a `DataFrame` which is then subject to normal rolling (not grouped).

Here is a solution that doesn't use `apply`, albeit a slower one:

```
B_shift = df.groupby('A').B.shift()
df['sum_B_previous_3'] = B_shift.groupby(df.A).rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum().values
```